# Match current directory with duplicity

Tags: duplicity

I am trying to include a folder in the current directory from where i'm backup up from.

`./example`

but I get a error!

```
cannot match any files in the base directory
```

I am 100% sure that the file exists

Comment: what is your command line? the parameters leading up to this error?

Comment: @ede I have the include file parameter and the file contains `./example`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue today, and I tried everything I could think of to have duplicity recognize a relative path, in the end, I just used the absolute paths instead (`/home/myuser/dir` instead of `~/dir` or `./dir`) and it works. It's not as *pretty* but it gets the job done.

Comment: I also did the same at end.